# How to check if a QPointF is in a QRect?

Tags: qt

I have a `widget` in center of `myWidget` and I used `mousePressEvent()` on `myWidget` to grab the mouse press event. I want to hide `myWidget` on mouse press but not when pressing inside the `widget`.
I can calculate the press position by `event->windowPos()` which gives a `QPointF` and also `ui->widget->rect()` which is a `QRect`.

how can I check if the `QpointF` is inside the `QRect`?

Comment: Are they in the same coordinate system already? Then http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#contains (while the math would be really trivial, too).

Comment: sorry, the rect is not on the same coordinate system

Comment: Don't compare the position of the mouse pointer to the rect of your widget. Compare it to the [geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) of the widget instead. I also think you have to use `event->pos()` instead of `event->windowPos()`.

Comment: I used `if (ui->widget->geometry().contains(event->pos()))
        return;` and it's OK. Thx.

Comment: send your comment as an asnwer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found another easy way to find if the press event occurred on the widget.

`if (ui->widget->underMouse())`
`doSomething();`

Answer (score 12):

Used:

```
if (ui->widget->geometry().contains(event->pos())) return;
```

Comment: To make a better response, I recommend reading: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can override the method `Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` and call `event->accept()` inside.
By doing this you would consume the mouse press event and it will not be propagated to the parent `myWidget`. So, `myWidget` will get just thouse events which happen outside the Widget geometry.

Comment: what if I cant override it because of dynamic declaration of `myWidget`?

Comment: Then you could use the function `Widget::childrenRegion()` inside the `Widget::mousePressEvent()` and check the event's position with `QRegion::contains(QPoint)`. I hope that helps.

Comment: You could also install an event| filter inside the `myWidget`  constructor `widget->installEventFilter(this)`. Then you will be able to receive all the events created for `myWidget` in the function `Widget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)` and simply ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Contains method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrect.html#contains) of QRect class

```
bool QRect::contains(const QPoint &point, bool proper = false) const
```

> Returns true if the given point is inside or on the edge of the
> rectangle, otherwise returns false. If proper is true, this function
> only returns true if the given point is inside the rectangle (i.e.,
> not on the edge).

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event){

    if(rect.contains(event->pos())){ // here rect is an object of QRect
        ...
    }
}
```